# Is there a way to use . separator in gradle extra properties

Tags: gradle

I am upgrading a build from Maven to Gradle. The existing build has defined a bunch of properties, to be used during tests. The property names use dot(.) as separators.

e.g.:

```
<database.host>localhost</database.host>
<database.port>1521</database.port>
<database.instance>mydb</database.instance>
...and many more like this
```

When I try to specify these properties:

```
ext {
    database.host = 'localhost'
    database.port = '1521'
    database.instance = 'sabrixdb'
}
```

in my build script I get exception:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'my-project'.
> Cannot get property 'database' on extra properties extension as it does not exist
```

Since these properties are too many, plus they are used in code tests, I don't want to change the names. i.e I don't want to change property 'database.host' to 'databaseHost'.

Can someone explain this error & if there is a way to specify these properties without changing their names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle have troubles with Maven style dotted property names because Gradle build scripts is basically Groovy scripts. So dot notation interpreted as object field access. You can try place your properties to gradle.properties file like this:

```
database.host=localhost
database.port=1521
database.instance=sabrixdb
```

And then access it in your Gradle build script like `project.properties['database.host']` or use Groovy string interpolation syntax for example to get human readable string:

```
"Database host: ${project.'database.host'}"
```

Comment: Thanks yanys for the quick answer, which did me understand gradle, more. Though when I added the properties entries to gradle.properties file, they were only available in the build script & not to the tests. So I ended up adding those to a properties file in test resources, which served the purpose. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

There a few ways to do this:

1. Use the map syntax: `ext['database.host'] = 'localhost'`
2. Explicitly call the **set()** method: `ext { set('database.host', 'localhost') }`
3. Put the properties in a **gradle.properties** file `database.host=localhost`